# php sql code not inserting into db

Tags: php, sql, file-upload

I'm new to php and a complete noob. I used following code to insert some files to my db.

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    

    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder="uploads/";


    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  



    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);


    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
        //mysql_query($sql, $conn);
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('successfully uploaded');
        window.location.href='index.php?success';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('error while uploading file');
        window.location.href='index.php?fail';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Though this save the file in upload folder, it does not insert anything into the data base. No matter how many times its uploaded database remain empty. It doesn't show any error either.
My config.php file is

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "dbtuts";
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

HTML part

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <button type="submit" name="btn-upload">upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You have commented out `mysql_query($sql, $conn);`, uncomment this and try !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No DB is selected

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "dbtuts";
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname); // <--- here select db first

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Then use

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    

    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $folder="uploads/";


    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  



    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);


    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);

    if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
        if($conn->query($sql)) {
          echo "Success";
        } else {
           echo "Failed. Error: ".$conn->error;
        }
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('successfully uploaded');
        window.location.href='index.php?success';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
    else
    {
        ?>
        <script>
        alert('error while uploading file');
        window.location.href='index.php?fail';
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\sim2\dbconfig.php on line 8

Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in C:\xampp\htdocs\sim2\dbconfig.php on line 8
Failed. Error:

Comment: after adding $dbname it worked. Thanks. '$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";'

Comment: I  have to change the answer please check it. You have to add 2nd part of the code block inside the if statement .

Answer (score 0):

I think, your sql can not get variable

You try to write like that:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);